# What level do you have to be to get missions for Simeon?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

What level do you have to be to get missions for Simeon on GTA 5 online? I am a level 8, and I have not received any calls from anyone while playing online.

Answer (score 1):

Missions from Simeon should start at level 5. And you call them to get missions.